# Finding minimum value in a list recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to find the minimum value in a list recursively. Since I'm still new in adapting to the recursive method, I would like to seek some help regarding my line of code:

```
listA = [9,-2,6,1,80,9,-2]

def findMinimum(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
       return l

    else:
       minNumber = findMinimum(l-1)
       min = listA[0]
       for i in listA:
           if listA[i]<listA[i+1]:
            min = listA[i]
            return min

findMinimum(listA)
```

I'll appreciate if anyone could help me out as I'm relatively new to recursion and my understanding is definitely up to standard.

Comment: `minNumber = findMinimum(l-1)` what do you mean by that? You cannot subtract an integer from a list. Do you mean `minNumber = findMinimum(l[:-1])`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis sorry it's my first try attempting a recursive function on my own. Pardon my low understanding on recursion. Thank you for that suggestion. It makes sense now

Answer (score 4):

The first part of your function is correct. But you should change the second part like this:

```
listA = [9,-2,6,1,80,9,-2]

def findMinimum(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
       return l[0]

    else:
       return min(l[0], findMinimum(l[1:]))

findMinimum(listA)
```

Remember, recursive functions comes to make our codes simpler and easier.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of your code is about right, but it has some mistakes. First, you should not be using `listA` inside of your function; `listA` is passed as an argument from the outside, and from within the function you should only refer to `l`. In the non-recursive case (where `len(l) == 1`), you should return `l[0]` (the minimum of a list with one element is that one element). Then, it is correct to call `findMinimum` inside your function again (that's the recursive call, as you know); however, what you probably want is to call it with the all the list `l` except the first element, that is, `l[1:]`. Then, you should compare the result `minNumber` to the first element of `l`; the idea is that you pick the smallest of `l[0]` and the minimum in `l[1:]`. Then you return the one you have chosen.

Additionally, you may want to consider the case when you get an empty list and throw an error; if you don't, you may get into an infinite recursion!

So a possible solution could be something like this:

```
listA = [9,-2,6,1,80,9,-2]

def findMinimum(l):
    if len(l) == 0:
       raise ValueError('Cannot find the minimum of an empty list.')
    elif len(l) == 1:
       return l[0]
    else:
       minNumber = findMinimum(l[1:])
       min = l[0]
       if minNumber < min:
            min = minNumber
       return min

findMinimum(listA)
```

Comment: thanks! the else statement was particularly helpful